# Ajax.ActionLink returns Login page within div when user need to login again

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, partial-views

I have a `Ajax.ActionLink` which results in a partial view being returned. However, if my `FormsAuthentication` expires and the user needs to login again, the whole Login page is returned as the partial view.

This results in the full login page appearing within the `div` I set aside for the partial view. So it looks like two web pages on the page.

I am using the `[Authorize]` attribute on my controller and actions.

How can I force the login page to be returned as a full view?

Answer (score 5):

You can extend the `[Authorize]` attribute so that you can override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` function to return a `JsonResult` to your AJAX call.

```
public class AuthorizeAjaxAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext 
                                                      filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // It was an AJAX request => no need to redirect
            // to the login url, just return a JSON object
            // pointing to this url so that the redirect is done 
            // on the client

            var referrer = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;

            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new { redirectTo = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + 
                            "?ReturnUrl=" + 
                             referrer.LocalPath.Replace("/", "%2f") }
            };
        }
        else
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Create a Javascript function handle the redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceStatus(result) {
        // if redirectTo has a value, redirect to the link
        if (result.redirectTo) {
            window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
        }
        else {
            // when the AJAX succeeds refresh the mydiv section
            $('#mydiv').html(result);
        }
    };
</script>
```

And then call that function in the OnSuccess option of your Ajax.ActionLink

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "GetStatus", 
                 new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="replaceStatus" })
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  I would suggest replacing the statement referrer.LocalPath.Replace("/", "%2f") with System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referrer.PathAndQuery) in case the AJAX action also takes arguments.